# How do I format a concatenated date in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a formula to convert a date in an excel column

`=CONCATENATE(YEAR([@[Admission Date]]),"-",MONTH([@[Admission Date]]))`

It produces a date like this "2014-1." For sorting purposes I need the date to look like this "2014-02" Is there a way to write that into the formula?

Thanks

Comment: why not just sort the date ?  Is there a way to write what into the formula?

Comment: Have you tried `TEXT(MONTH([@[Admission Date]])),"mm")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=DATE(YEAR([@[Admission Date]]), MONTH([@[Admission Date]]), 1)
' as strictly text (not recommended)
=TEXT([@[Admission Date]], "yyyy-mm")
```

Format the column as *yyyy-mm*. Always work with real numbers and real dates whenever you can. There is more than enough variations available with [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) to make it *look* like you want while rtaining an underlying numerical value.

Comment: I agree with jeeped, keeping the date as the date instead of text will usually save you effort later down the road if you wind up trying to manipulate the date information again.  Much better just to change your display formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple enough if you add an "if" statement so that it will add a "0" before the number if it's < 10

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1),"-",IF(MONTH(B1)>10,MONTH(B1),CONCATENATE("0",MONTH(B1))))
```

The logic behind it is: `if "b1 > 10" then (leave it as is) else concatenate("0",month(b1))`

Comment: `RIGHT("0"&MONTH([@[Admission Date]]), 2)` works as well.

Comment: @Daniel B1 >= 10, I do not think you want to be adding a 0 in front of the 10 month. Alternately b1>9.

Comment: @jeeped I liked the "RIGHT" approach and only pulling the last two.  I have to confess I have done the if statement for adding 0 in the past on several similar circumstances.  I will try and remember the "Right approach as it is cleaner!

Comment: @ForwardEd thanks! I hadn't really tested it, you're definitely right about that :)